# How to make PasswordBox ReadOnly in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am making a PasswordBox that exposes the password for a specific account when the cursor hovers over the PasswordBox. However this is purely for viewing purposes and I don't want the user to be able to edit the password.

How can I make the PasswordBox ReadOnly like you can with textboxes? I know it doesn't have that same property to set but is there a work around for PasswordBoxes in UWP that will work?

Here is what I have so far:
View.xaml

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="Password" Password="{x:Bind Acct.Password}" CornerRadius="5" PointerEntered="Password_PointerEntered"
     PointerExited="Password_PointerExited" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Width="175"  />
```

View.xaml.cs

```
        private void Password_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pb = sender as PasswordBox;
            pb.PasswordRevealMode = PasswordRevealMode.Visible;
        }

        private void Password_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pb = sender as PasswordBox;
            pb.PasswordRevealMode = PasswordRevealMode.Hidden;
        }
```

So far what I have tried is trying to make the PasswordBox lose focus after it gains focus by being clicked on to edit, but haven't had much luck there. Is there a way to cancel events when they happen?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the great help of the other answers with solve 2 other problems similar to mine I was able to discover a solution for my specific application.

Using `AllowFocusOnInterface="False"` on the PasswordBox in XAML, I achieved the ability to reveal password on hover over and make it so users could not click on and edit the PasswordBox.

Thanks everyone for your help! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could react to the `PasswordChanged` event and use it to set back your `PasswordBox.Password` property to its initial value, like:

```cs
private void PasswordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Password.Password = "cannot-be-changed password";
}
```

You could additionally also make your `PasswordBox` immune to focus with `IsHitTestVisible="False"` and `"Focusable="False"` markup. This won't prevent the user from modifying the password but it will indicate him that this is not supported. This might mess with your `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` events though.

Comment: Just tried the IsHitTestVisible and you're right, it stops the Pointer events from working. I also noticed that I don't have a Focusable option. Is that only available in WPF or something? I couldn't find it in UWP. This solution definitely works if I wasn't also trying to use the Pointer events, so thank you for the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.previewkeydown) event and catch all pressed keys.

```
<PasswordBox PreviewKeyDown="OnPreviewKeyDown" />

private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: This does in fact work for not allowing typing, although it does allow selection of the box still. Thank you for this answer though, very helpful just doesn't do what is fully intended for my application. Will thumbs up and add my solution i found to my specific problem.